# Real-Time Human Pose Recognition in Parts from Single Depth Images

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, kinect, pose-estimation

I have been reading this paper and there is point not clear to me. For their algorithm they are using body parts, but i couldn't find how they obtain the body part. Is there any straight forward method for obtaining body parts?

[paper link](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/145347/BodyPartRecognition.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

In the [supplementary material](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/145347/SupplementaryMaterial.pdf) published by Microsoft at [this link](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/?id=145347), authors explain they used labeled 3D models to train the algorithm. So the body parts used for the training were "hand-labeled" for each of the models used.

This image should help to figure out how the labeling process were made:

[image: 3D labeled models]

Comment: Hi Vito thank you answer, But they were mentioning they used real data also for building training trees. How can they partition the body on real depth image

Comment: I read authors mention some "mocap data", so I think they probably used [mo-cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_capture) to move such 3D models and morph them in several poses.